# how to use option on a multimap in scala

Tags: scala

I have map and mutlimap, because map can't have duplicate keys, decide to try and implement multip so i can have dup keys.

```
def ListofConnections1(key : String): List[String] = {
  Iterator.iterate(Option(key))(o => db.get(o.head))
    .takeWhile(_.nonEmpty).flatten.toList
}
```

Like wise the same as above in multi map is implemented, but the difference is we have 100 as key twice acceptable due to multimap

```
    import collection.mutable.{ HashMap, MultiMap, Set }
val mm = new HashMap[String, Set[String]] with MultiMap[String, String]

mm.addBinding("100", "101")
mm.addBinding("100", "102")


    def ListofConnections2(key : String): List[String] = {
  Iterator.iterate(Option(key))(o => mm.toMap.get(o.head))
    .takeWhile(_.nonEmpty).flatten.toList
}
```

I am trying to use this function like above but i get different errors like, i am not sure how to use the `option` alias `o` here to

```
    found   : Option[scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]]
 required: Option[String]
             Iterator.iterate(Option(key))(o => mm.get(o.head))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you;

```
def ListofConnections2(key : String): List[String] = mm.get(key) match {
  case None => Nil
  case Some(keys) =>
    keys.toList ++ keys.flatMap(ListofConnections2)
}
```

Comment: can you explain or add comments plz :) the last like case some statement

Comment: We have a key. We ask the multiMap for values: `mm.get(key)`.
IF the result is `None` there are no values and we end with `Nil` which is the empty `List`.
If we get some values `Some(keys)` then we return them `keys.toList`, plus `++` ListofConnections2 called on each of the new keys, flattened: `keys.flatMap(ListofConnections2`

Comment: Note that this could easily cause an endless loop, non-terminating program, or stack overflow if there is a circular reference.

Comment: would an iterator like the above example in OP be better option?

Comment: I don't think building an Iterator like you have is better - it should produce the same answer but seems to be more difficult to use, and I find it less readable. It will not avoid an endless loop for `Map("100" -> "100")` which you will also encounter with your first solution.

Comment: Here is a modification of my function that will not follow circular references. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/SDF1ptflRw6f8uywx4S5UQ

Comment: i also need to include the orginal key "100" in the result list. Without your circular reference midfication(orginal function) doesn't add to the. So no matter circular ref or not key or 100 in the case should be added to the output. where would i add this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160143/discussion-between-retrospectacus-and-dedpo).

Comment: also seems like 101, and 102 appeared twice in that list as well. 
It should be List(100, 101, 102, 106, 107, 111, 112)